# Why are these subtree assertions failing?

Tags: git, assertion, git-subtree

I am attempting to use `git subtree` to split my repository into multiple repositories while maintaining all history. In this case, I am trying to split individual files out of a main repository into their own repositories so they can be maintained as independent projects.

I tried to run the command

```
git subtree split -P lib/a.lua -b temp
```

but got the following output:

```
assertion failed:  test blob = tree -o blob = commit
assertion failed:  test blob = tree -o blob = commit
assertion failed:  test blob = tree -o blob = commit
…
```

What does this mean? What am I doing wrong? My directory looks like this:

```
project
 ├ main.lua
 └ lib
    ├ a.lua
    └ b.lua
```

Comment: What has this to do with Microsoft's command processor.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What do you think the subtree split command will do?

Comment: @CatCat probably a mis-tag as the OP is likely to be using CMD to run the commands.

Comment: @CatCat My bad, I don't know what I was thinking when I added that tag

Comment: @evolutionxbox Doesn't it take the history for a directory and split it out of the main repository into its own repository?

Comment: I honestly don’t know without researching. I had hoped you might add your expectations to the question.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Oh, I see. I can do that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, @nethergranite figured it out. Git's git-subtree may not be able to track individual files for `git-subtree --split`, at least in some present versions.

I've discovered a similar error from git-subtree when trying to recover some deleted code from the GNU Emacs 'lisp/obsolete' directory – namely, one `scribe.el`. When I ran `git-subtree -P <file-pathname> [other-args]` Git similarly began emitting the `assertion failed` mesage.

Alternately, using the syntax e.g

```
git subtree split -b split_${changest_ID} --annotate="split lisp/obsolete:" -P lisp/obsolete/
```

... then it runs just fine, using the relative directory as a prefix for git-subtree(1)

For admin purposes, the changest_ID can be retrieved with e.g

```
git log --pretty=short --abbrev-commit -n1 -- relpath/to/subdir/
```

...futhermore, parsing for the commit refererence (ID) with text tools e.g

```
git log --pretty=short --abbrev-commit -n1 -- relpath/to/subdir/ | head -n1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

The derived branch name -- split_${changest_ID} -- can then be used to push the directory's subtree to a local, bare git repository, from which it can then be managed independent of the original source tree … license/linkage/redist stipulations permitting. Further documentation may be available in the git-subtree(1) manual page.

Beside all that, it seems git-subtree may simply need a directory prefix, rather than an individual file as prefix -- pending any revisions to its source code as such, if git-subtree ever may theoretically create a subtree from a single file prefix, insofar as how git manages its internal state in a Git repository.

Comment: This got me out of one pickle, but it's failing on my latest pickle. I'm not sure what's different.